# Gemfile ruby version, rvm and bundler

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundler

My gemfile says:

```
ruby "1.8.7"
```

`ruby -v` says:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [i686-darwin12.5.0]
```

`rvm list` says:

```
=> ruby-1.8.7-p374 [ i686 ]
ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ x86_64 ]
* ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]
```

But `bundle check` says:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 1.8.7
```

What's goin' on?

Comment: cd into the folder that contains `Gemfile` and then run `ruby -v`. You may be having a `.ruby-version` or `.rvmrc` which might be switching ruby version. Are you sure `rvm list` shows only one entry? Then where did `ruby 2.0.0` came from?

Comment: gem install bundler fixed it all. I'll post the entire answer to explain why in 8 hours, not enough reputation ;-)

Comment: @Eternal-Learner I've edited the entire rvm list output. I did not put it all at once because I supposed the "=>" rvm mark would speak for itself

Answer (score 1):

at the prompt type

- `rvm list`

and see which versions of ruby you get in your environment probably is directed to version 2.0 ...

if there is a version of ruby-1.8.7-P374 of the command

- `rvm install ruby-1.8.7-P374`

and then

- `rvm use ruby-1.8.7-P374`

This should fix

Comment: `Rvm use ruby-1.8.7-P374` isn't correct. The command is `rvm` because *nix is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what I had missed

My ruby 1.8.7 was a fresh install

I had no gems installed for this ruby

the `bundle` command did not fails because it defaulted to ~/.rvm/bin/bundle, which pointed to the ruby 2.0.0 bundle command

after installing bundler under ruby 1.8.7, things went back to normal

I believe there could be a warning (or a better warning) when calling the `bundle` command under a ruby without the gem installed.